# Why I need extra `-k` flag when I curl over ip rather than hostname?

Tags: http, curl, https

I have this code

```
$ curl  "https://api.weixin.qq.com:443/sns/jscode2session?appid=a&secret=b&js_code=c&grant_type=authorization_code"
```

and it can get response from server like the following

```
{"errcode":40013,"errmsg":"invalid appid rid: 5f96703e-5e24e4f1-691a9221"}
```

However when I try to replace hostname into ip, I failed with the following message

```
$ host api.weixin.qq.com
api.weixin.qq.com has address 180.97.7.108
api.weixin.qq.com has address 101.226.212.27

$ curl  "https://101.226.212.27:443/sns/jscode2session?appid=a&secret=b&js_code=c&grant_type=authorization_code"
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '101.226.212.27'
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I hanve to add `-k` to make this work

```
$ curl  "https://101.226.212.27:443/sns/jscode2session?appid=a&secret=b&js_code=c&grant_type=authorization_code" -k
{"errcode":40013,"errmsg":"invalid appid rid: 5f967132-1ee77e4b-2f378192"}c
```

I want to know why this happen, and if there is any secure problems here? If there is any, how can I remove this `-k` flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without `-k` (or the long version `--insecure`), curl makes sure that the host you connect to (specified in the URL) is also correctly mentioned in the certificate provided by the server when it connects to it, as part of the TLS handshake. The check is done to make sure that it speaks to the legitimate machine.

The server certificate contains a list of host names (or wildcards) that curl checks if they match the host name in the URL.

When you specify an IP address in the URL, curl can only use that to compare against the names in the certificate. A server *can* still list specific IP addresses (`https://1.1.1.1` is for example known to) but is very rare and rather exceptional.

### The better fix

Instead of using the IP address in the command line, use `--resolve` to use the right host name *and* make sure curl connects to the exact IP address of your choice.

### Warning

Using `-k` completely disables curl's certificate check and you may then be subject for a MITM attack without being able to detect that.

Comment: So attack may happen when I trying to resolve `api.weixin.qq.com` into `101.226.212.27` because we are at risk of dns hijacking. If I can make sure `101.226.212.27` is the exact IP I want, then there will be no secure problem?

Comment: No. This fully disables any certificate checks. I'd suggest you look at the --resolve option of curl.

Comment: Meanwhile, I think if I decide to curl an IP, and the conenction is established smoothly, I can always get this warning, except for several IPs?

Comment: By the way, -k is an alias for --insecure